# How to disable event temporarily

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, events

I have datagridview that has cell validating event so user has to fill cell on column[0] before leave that cell

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill this field");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
```

i want to delete row with a button even when all cells on that row is empty, but every time i click DeleteRow_btn the validation message show

```
private void DeleteRow_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count < 1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }
        }
```

i already try

```
private void DeleteRow_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        dataGridView1.CellValidating -= dataGridView1_CellValidating;
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }
        dataGridView1.CellValidating += dataGridView1_CellValidating;
}
```

but it wont work, i know why, but i dont know how to solve this
thanks for your time, sorry about my english anyway

Comment: Check if event handler is attached at more than one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the cell is validating when you leave it in order to click the delete button, but before the click occurs. Therefore detaching the event in the click event handler will have no effect.

The solution is to display the validation message only if the row is not empty. I.e. if all the cells are empty, no validation message should appear.

```
bool isRowEmpty = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells
    .Cast<Cell>()
    .All(cell => IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.FormattedValue.ToString()));
if (isRowEmpty) {
    // validate
}
```